# EF 4.1 Code First - cyclical reference issue (MVC 3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to solve this issue with my domain model.
I have made a simplified example of what I'm dealing with - using two parent classes and two child classes.

I have multiple paths from the parents to the children:

- Parent1 --> Child1
- Parent1 --> Child2
- Parent1 --> Parent2 --> Child1
- Parent2 --> Child1

This gives me the following error: {"The referential relationship will result in a cyclical reference that is not allowed. [ Constraint name = Child1_Parent2 ]"}

I know it is because there is multiple cascade paths, but I don't know how to fix the issue. Can I do it with annotations or do I need to use fluent mapping?

I would like the model to function like this:

- If Parent1 is deleted: Child1 should be deleted, Child2 should *not* be deleted.
- If Parent2 is deleted: Parent1 *and* Child1 should be deleted, Child2 should *not* be deleted.
- If Child1 is deleted: Only Child1 is deleted.
- If Child2 is deleted: Only Child2 is deleted.

Here are the classes:

**Parent1**

```
public class Parent1
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Parent2 Parent2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child1> Children1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child2> Children2 { get; set; }

    public Parent1()
    {
        Children1 = new List<Child1>();
        Children2 = new List<Child2>();
    }
}
```

**Parent2**

```
public class Parent2
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child1> Children1 { get; set; }

    public Parent2()
    {
        Children1 = new List<Child1>();
    }
}
```

**Child1**

```
public class Child1
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Parent1 Parent1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Parent2 Parent2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Child2**

```
public class Child2
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Parent1 Parent1 { get; set; }
}
```